# make multiple pdf with puppeteer but some pdf Invalid or corrupted PDF file

Tags: node.js, pdf, puppeteer

im using puppeteer version 19.8.5, nodejs v18.16, momentjs and axios to fetch api. I try make multiple pdf from webpage url, but sometime few pdf Invalid or corrupted PDF file without any error message

here my code
https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-moon-pks6sx

here invalid pdf ss
[image: invalid pdf without message error]